# React update the parents status from one child and pass the updated value to a new child

Tags: reactjs, class, state

I have a ReactJS class which has the following structure

```
-----parent 
|----- child 1 
|----- child 2
```

The child 1 updates a variable in parent which should be consumed by
child 2 which handles the display.

I am able to pass the value to child 2 during the first update. But with the further updates in parent's variable by child 1, I am unable to pass the updated variable to the child 2 for display.

Is there a method I can achieve this in ReactJS class?

Including the code:

```
class Parent extends Component {
this.state = {
    value: [],
    tempValue: []
    }

onDataChange (val) => {
    this.setState({
        tempValue:val
    })
}

onFirstChange =() => {
    this.setState({
        value:[...value, tempValue]
    )}
}


render (){
    return(
        <Button onClick={this.onFirstChange}
        <Child getValue={this.onDataChange} />

        {
            this.state.value?
            <SecondChild value={this.state.value} />
        }
        )
    }
}
```

Every time the button is clicked, the Child updates the "value" in parent which should be read by the "SecondChild". But until "value" is populated, the SecondChild should not execute

Comment: maybe adding some of your code here will help clarify what you might be doing wrong. 
you basically should have the variable saved in state in `parent` and passed down to `child two`. then pass the setter function for the state variable from the parent to `child 1`.  react will handle the rest of it.

Comment: Please post code

Comment: why do you need tempValue ?

Comment: There are multiple values sent from Child1 and the status in parent is updated after all the values from Child1 are completed using a ok button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Parent {
  constructor(){
   this.state = {
     commonVariable: defaultValue
   }
  }

  updateCommonVariable = (newValue) => {
    this.setState({commonVariable: newValue})
  }

  render(){
    <Child1 updateCommonVariable={this.updateCommonVariable} />
    {this.state.commonVariable && <Child2 commonVariable={this.state.commonVariable} />}
  }
}
```

- calling `this.props.updateCommonVariable` in `Child1` will update the `commonVariable` in the parent as well as the `Child2`
- and in `Child2`, `this.props.commonVariable` will always be the updated value from the parent.

Comment: There are some texts in the Child2 class that I want displayed only when there is a value in commonVariable.

Comment: Yes. That was very helpful. Thank you.